# Save List items from html table to Mysql

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to save a list of items from an html table in mysql, but it gives me an error:
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long[]'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{ID}".

My Code is:

Entity Class is

```
   package com.gadpo.cga.app.models.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name = "paquetes")
public class Paquete implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String detalle;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="fecha")
    private Date fecha;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="paquete_id")
    private List<Actividad> actividades;
    
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="paquete_id")
    private List<ItemPaquete> items;
    
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy = "paquete", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //private List<Usuario> usuarios;
    
    
    public List<ItemPaquete> getItems() {
        return items;
    }



    public void setItems(List<ItemPaquete> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Planificacion planificacion;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public String getDetalle() {
        return detalle;
    }



    public void setDetalle(String detalle) {
        this.detalle = detalle;
    }



    public List<Actividad> getActividades() {
        return actividades;
    }



    public void setActividades(List<Actividad> actividades) {
        this.actividades = actividades;
    }
    


    public Planificacion getPlanificacion() {
        return planificacion;
    }



    public void setPlanificacion(Planificacion planificacion) {
        this.planificacion = planificacion;
    }
    
    


    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }



    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }




    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }



    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public void addItemPaquete(ItemPaquete item) {
        items.add(item);
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
}
```

Controller is:

```
package com.gadpo.cga.app.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.gadpo.cga.app.models.entity.ItemPaquete;
import com.gadpo.cga.app.models.entity.Paquete;
import com.gadpo.cga.app.models.entity.Planificacion;
import com.gadpo.cga.app.models.entity.Usuario;
import com.gadpo.cga.app.models.service.IUsuarioService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/paquete")
@SessionAttributes("paquete")
public class PaqueteController {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioService usuarioService;
    
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    @GetMapping("/form/{planificacionId}")
    public String crear(@PathVariable(value="planificacionId") Long planificacionId, Map<String, Object> model, RedirectAttributes flash) {
        
        Planificacion planificacion=usuarioService.findPlanificacionById(planificacionId);
        
        if(planificacion==null) {
            flash.addFlashAttribute("error","La planificación no existe en la bd");
            return "redirect:/listar";
        }
        Paquete paquete = new Paquete();
        paquete.setPlanificacion(planificacion);
        model.put("paquete", paquete);
        model.put("titulo", "Registro de paquete");
        
        return "paquete/form";
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value="/cargar-usuarios/{term}", produces= {"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody List<Usuario>cargarUsuarios(@PathVariable String term){
        return usuarioService.findByApellido(term);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/form")
    public String guardar(@Valid Paquete paquete,BindingResult result,Model model, 
            @RequestParam(name="item_id[]",required = false) Long [] itemId,RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status) {
        
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("titulo", "Registrar nuevo paquete");
            return "paquete/form";
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<itemId.length;i++) {
            //System.out.println("ID del usuario: "+itemId[i]);
            Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findUsuarioById(itemId[i]);
            ItemPaquete linea = new ItemPaquete();
            linea.setUsuario(usuario);
            paquete.addItemPaquete(linea);
            log.info("ID: "+itemId[i].toString());
        }
        
    /*  if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("titulo", "Formulario de paquete");
            return "paquete/form";
        }*/
        usuarioService.savePaquete(paquete);
        status.setComplete();
        flash.addFlashAttribute("success","Paquete creado con éxito!");
        
        return "redirect:listar";
    }
    
    
    
}
```

and my form is

[form_paquete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSkpR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening in your `PaqueteController` class in the `public String guardar` method. Your controller is expecting a `java.util.Long` array (itemId) but is receiving a String instead.

First, you have to remove the `[]` in your `@RequestParam(name="item_id[]")`.

Then, make sure that the Post requesting you are sending is like:

```
{
    "item_id": [1,2,3],
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my form plantilla-items.html the name of td is item_id[]

The code in plantilla-items is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <table th:fragment="itemsPaquete" class="d-none">
        <tbody id="plantillaItemsPaquete">
            <tr id="row_{ID}">
                <td class="d-none"><input type="hidden" value="{ID}"
                    name="item_id[]" /></td>
                <td>{ID}</td> 
                <td>{NOMBRE}</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                    onclick="itemsHelper.eliminarLineaFactura({ID});">x</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMAkb.png)

When check the request in the brownser, the first element is a string "{ID}" and no understand